# connect to github enterprise from egit over https with a self signed certificate

Tags: eclipse, git, https, egit, github-enterprise

I am trying to clone a git repo from a github enterprise server over https from egit but I am getting the following error:

```
  https://myServer/myOrg/myRepo.git: cannot open git-upload-pack:
  https://myServer/myOrg/myRepo.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
```

I've tried adding the following to my .gitconfig but I'm am getting the same error.

```
[http]
sslVerify = false
```

I am able to clone a repo from my github enterprise server with msysgit without any problems. I can also successfully clone a repo on github using egit or msysgit. 
I'm using version 2.1.0 of EGit.
Our git server is not behind a proxy and it is using basic authentication.

Any idea why I can't clone from egit.

Comment: And you don't have a proxy configured in Eclipse? The problem could be that it *is* trying over the proxy when it shouldn't.

Comment: Nope I don't have a proxy configured in eclipse. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

By setting following worked for me

```
[http]
sslVerify = false
```

Please ensure eclipse is configured with the right .gitconfig file you are modifying

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration

"Location" option must point to correct .gitconfig file e.g H:\.gitconfig

If you don't want to edit .gitconfig file directly, you can configure as below

Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration -> New Entry -> http.sslverify=false